# How can I make PHP perform multiple calls from an array to a script and wait for each function to end before moving on?

Tags: php, loops, asynchronous, callback

I have an array of properties which contains a list of properties and their .ics locations (.ics being an iCal text file of dates and events). I can run my script for any of the array elements one at a time manually with perfect result, but when I try to loop through the script with a while loop it fails consistently having done the first property in the array and part of the second one. Note: The $this->mymodel->import() function takes .5 - .8 seconds to run.

This is what the property array looks like:

```
$propsArray = array (
    array('Property 1', '83736363G', 'http://blah.ics'),
    array('Property 2', '83726433H', 'http://blah.ics'),
    array('Property 3', '62727438J', 'http://blah.ics'),
    array('Property 4', '12345356Y', 'http://blah.ics'),
    array('Property 5', '28373657D', 'http://blah.ics'),
    array('Property 6', '93377656K', 'http://blah.ics'),
    array('Property 7', '11223343L', 'http://blah.ics'),
...
);
```

So I use a foreach loop to loop through the array and call the function in my model like so:

```
foreach($propsArray as $property) {
      $propertyName = $property[0];
      $this->mymodel->import($property[1], $property[2]);
  }
```

Running $this->mymodel->import($property[1], $property[2]); manually with each individual property works perfectly every time. It's only when I loop that I get a problem. No error by the way, the script just 'hangs'. I thought it might be a JS, sync/async type problem which would need a callback or something to run the next item in the loop only when the previous one finishes. Any ideas of what to do would be helpful.

Comment: If `import()` takes 5-8 seconds and you have 7 properties to import, that's up to a minute already. No surprise that it "hangs" and eventually times out...

Comment: `max_execution_time` in php.ini I think is default 30 seconds. Might try increasing it.

Comment: could you show us method `import()`

Comment: @Niet "No surprise that it "hangs". No surprise that what hangs? And why are you not surprised? does the foreach time out if something doesn't come back in quicker thant a few seconds? An elaboration would be good to help me understand

Comment: The whole script is expected to take at least a minute just from what you've shown (and the `...` implies there's more). PHP scripts by default time out after 30 seconds, as AbraCadaver mentioned.

Comment: Now I understand what you guys are saying. I didn't realize that the total execution time would include all of the execution times of all of the script calls. In other words, that the foreach would time out after max_execution_time - dunno why I never copped on to that. So, is there a better approach to making this happen? I guess increasing the max_execution time could work but this array is bigger than shown above in reality and has more stuff added all the time so it's not a known maximum. I thought about using callbacks? Would that be a better approach?

Comment: Wondering if anyone came up with any ideas on this? I haven't been able to make anything work. Wondering if async calls might be the way? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so how often is this run? How is it run? If it's every hour, takes 5 minutes, and run by a scheduled task - up the limit for execution. Problem solved (at least, for now) - you can add a line at the top: `set_time_limit(0);`. This will allow it to run as long as it takes.

What you **must** be careful of is that you leave a good amount of headroom so that processes don't overlap. If you run the script every 6 minutes, and it takes 5 minutes, you only need a few slower-than-usual transactions and then processes overlap - this will cause the second to run slower, the third will come in even slower and eventually (quite quickly) the server will lock up.

Think a bit about the nature of the problem.

Do they need to run in order? Does it matter if one fails? Is this list going to stay the same size?

Stepping up and out of the single script might give you more room to move but it adds complexity. If the answer to the above questions is "no" or "maybe not", then you might consider a message queue/worker architecture, for example. Then you can scale the number of workers for the amount of jobs and they can run concurrently or just keep one worker and it can run each, as and when it gets to it.

Comment: Thanks OK sure. (it's .5 secs per array item by the way). I want to run the script every 30 mins. A cron job runs a controller every 30 mins. One cron for each property in the script - separate cron jobs calling https://myserver.com/import/propertyId . One per property. Problem is that it ends up just firing a whole bunch of these scripts on the half hour with no pause in between, maybe that's a lot of pressure to put on the server every half hour... but maybe not. Point of the foreach was to get more control over the process maybe with a sleep(8) in between each request - but this also fails.

Comment: @Wittner how many array items are there? When you say it fails - what's the error?

Comment: There are approx 60 items to do.  A foreach calls the model which imports the ical url using cURL, parses the data, updates DB table with any calendar changes. I have no PHP error per say - the script just 'hangs'. I have an echo in the model which echoes 'working...' before the cURL request and then returns with property code and success message after DB update which echoes to the page. First property returns 'working...' , then property code and success message on completion. Second property returns 'working...', then.... nothing, no more output. Reducing items to 3 or 4 makes no difference.

Comment: Might be out of look with queues. This application is a legacy app on a shared server so no access to CLI and older version of CodeIgniter. My current stuff on Laravel would have a chance but not this. Maybe when I've moved it to a newer, DigitalOcen server

Comment: Outputting to a browser won't complete until all tasks have finished. If it has 3 items, and takes .5 to do each, it should be done in under 10 seconds. If not, then it must be hanging on an item which suggests an issue with your underlying import method

Comment: Yep. Although running each task individually works fine, and with proper outputs. If I replace the tasks with an 8 second delay and no other code it works fine. Frustrating.

Comment: I think there must be an issue with running the import where it's not leaving the `mymodel` object in a useable state - just a guess. What happens if you just put hardcoded values and just run `$this->mymodel->import('XXX', 'XXX');` twice